# Is there a most efficient way to produce a table in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

It duplicates the`TableRow`and displays it as shown in the image. Is there a more efficient way?
Also, are there any articles or sites where I can learn more about xml for creating Android layouts?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#E3AFFA"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:radius="100dp"
            >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sun"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mon"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="1sp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tue"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="1sp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wed"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="1sp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Thu"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="1sp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fri"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="1sp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sat"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="1sp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    </TableRow>...
```

[image: Image of the application]

Comment: `are there any articles or sites where I can learn more about`... this is off-topic for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficient way to produce a table is using **Table layout with RecyclerView**.

You can checkout the following link for complete understanding :

https://mustafaimran71.medium.com/table-layout-with-recycler-view-in-kotlin-d5224d8b8a34